# trying to create a hover ul function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just trying to create a simple hover over `ul` that displays a menu. Any suggestions for improvement?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    body{ margin: 0px; text-align: center; height:2000px;}

                    nav {
                        color:white;
                        background-color:black;
                        width:100%;
                        height:60px;
                    }

                     nav ul {
                            margin:0;
                            padding:0;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            list-style:none;
                            position: relative;
                     }


                    nav ul li {
                        padding-top:11px;
                        float:left;
                        display:inline-block;
                    }

                    nav ul li a {
                            display: block;
                            color:white;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            height:45px;
                            width: 200px;
                            line-height: 43px;
                            text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    nav ul ul {
                    position:absolute;
                    width:150px;
                    ;
                    }
                    nav ul ul li {
                    display:block;
                    background: black;
                    }


                </style>
                <script>
                    var child  = document.getElementById("child");
                    function displayNav() {
                        if(child) {
                            child.style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            child.display.style = "block";
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <nav>
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#">Practice Hover</a>
                            <ul onmouseover="displayNav(this)" id = "child">
                                <li><a href="#">Pr</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ac</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ti</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ce</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: First, get rid of the javascript, which are absolutely not needed, then create a menu using CSS.

Comment: im trying to practice javascript, theres no need for that comment @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: "Correction and explanation" ...? You haven't given us any specific problems yet...

Comment: Then learn to use javascript for what javascript is for - enhancing functionality. There is no need for js to create this, that's my point. Create a working menu in CSS first, then you can add bells and whistles with JS if you absolutely need to.

Comment: ahh sorry, just trying to get it to hide and then display using javascript. im merely doing this for practice with javascript using mouseover.people seem to be getting upset that im asking a question.

Comment: @JAAulde if your going to criticize people for asking questions(yes i get it was unspecific at first) when simply just practicing and being curious, i highly suggest you take that attitude somewhere else. i didnt ask to be reprimanded. simply experimenting.

Comment: @JAAulde wrong person meant for junk food

Comment: Well, the current js you have won't work, most likely, first because what you're hovering over is not the `ul` inside the `li`, but the `a`. And specifying that you're doing this to learn is good, but the concept still displays as "I want this menu to show on hover, with js", which makes no sense, because there is no need to do this with js. The best way to learn is to use examples (and try to recreate them) that makes sense to use in real life as well. Also, I ponder that ` if(child)` will always return true in that function. Do a `console.log(child)` and see what it returns.

Comment: thank you, i do appreciate that comment @junk

Answer (score 1):

No JS, just CSS.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
ul ul {
  display: none;
  }
.child:hover ul {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul> 
  <li class="child"><a href="#">Practice Hover</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Pr</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ac</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ti</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ce</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```